# Computing powers of -1

Tags: language-agnostic

Is there an established idiom for implementing `(-1)^n * a`?

The obvious choice of `pow(-1,n) * a` seems wasteful, and `(1-2*(n%2)) * a` is ugly and not perfectly efficient either (two multiplications and one addition instead of just setting the sign). I think I will go with `n%2 ? -a : a` for now, but introducing a conditional seems a bit dubious as well.

Comment: If this is language agnostic why are you using a specific syntax? There could exist a language which could process `(-1)^n * a` efficiently.

Comment: I would go with pow(-1,n) * a. It's most easily understood by the reader. It's hard to say since you are not talking about a particular language, but there is a good chance pow() has some optimizations/special cases already done inside it. Look up a C implementation for example, it's likely nothing like what you might expect.

Comment: The point in marking this question language agnostic is that languages usually agree on the functionality they provide, see e.g. `atan2` or `2<<n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making certain assumptions about your programming language, compiler, and CPU...

To repeat the conventional -- and correct -- wisdom, do not even think about optimizing this sort of thing unless your profiling tool says it is a bottleneck. If so, `n % 2 ? -a : a` will likely generate very efficient code; namely one `AND`, one test against zero, one negation, and one conditional move, with the `AND`+test and negation independent so they can potentially execute simultaneously.

Another option looks something like this:

```
zero_or_minus_one = (n << 31) >> 31;
return (a ^ zero_or_minus_one) - zero_or_minus_one;
```

This assumes 32-bit integers, arithmetic right shift, defined behavior on integer overflow, twos-complement representation, etc. It will likely compile into four instructions as well (left shift, right shift, `XOR`, and subtract), with a dependency between each... But it can be better for certain instruction sets; e.g., if you are vectorizing code using SSE instructions.

Incidentally, your question will get a *lot* more views -- and probably more useful answers -- if you tag it with a specific language.

Answer (score 0):

As others have written, in most cases, readability is more important than performance and compilers, interpreters and libraries are better at optimizing than most people think. Therfore `pow(-1,n) * a` is likely to be an efficient solution on your platform.

If you really have a performance issue, your own suggestion `n%2 ? -a : a` is fine. I don't see a reason to worry about the conditional assignment.

If your language has a bitwise AND operator, you could also use `n & 1 ? -a : a` which should be very efficient even without any optimization. It is likely that on many platforms, this is what `pow(a,b)` actually does in the special case of `a == -1` and `b` being an integer.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that compilers will readily transform `n%2` into `n&1`. Less confident about `pow(-1, n)` - the behavior is different for non-integer n.